# Is it possible to come up with a formula for upper bound for this?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, sieve-theory

Consider a sieve, where the only numbers left are $n \equiv 5 mod (6)$

So the sieve has 5, 11, 17, 23...

**Where the gap is uniform and is 6, initially.**

Now we'll continue to sieve out the multiples of prime numbers starting from 5.
Now 35, 65, 95... are sieved out

After this the gap among the numbers is no more uniform and the max gap is 12, min gap is 6.

If we go on sieveing out multiples of prime numbers, at any stage is there a way to estimate the upper bound of max gap among the numbers left, after multiples of all the numbers, till a given number is sieved out?

Let the function be $G(n)$ where $n$ is the prime number, till which it is sieved.

So $G(5) = 12$

Is there any way where we can come up with a formula for $G(n)$?
If not an exact formula is it atleast possible to calculate the upper bound?

---

Some observations:

1. $G(n)$ is always multiple of 6 and it goes on increasing.
2. $G(n)$ where $n$ is not a prime number is same as $G(m)$ where $m$ is a prime number just less than $n$. For eg: $G(6) = G(5)$

Comment: There is no upper bound, as the gap between consecutive primes has no upper bound, and the numbers left after exhaustive sieving are primes.

Comment: @KeithBackman oh no no you have missed the question. Upper bound after only prime untill a particular prime is sieved. Like G(5) is the gap after 2, 3, 5 are primed. The gap is 12. So I'm trying to generralise it for G(n). All the primes are sieved.

Answer (score 1):

I will do $G(7),G(17)$ to illustrate a point, for $G(7)$ we need $x$ such that $6x+5 = 0 \mod 5$ and $ 6(x+1)+5=0 \mod 7$ since we are dealing with primes and $gcd(6,p)=1$ for $p\geq 5$ prime number then there is a solution using Chinese remainder theorem and $x= 25$ so $6*25+5 , 6*26+5 = 155,161$ are sieved out, and in general for $p_k = n$ we can make a system of $\pi(n)-1$(excluding 2,3) equations meaning we can sieve out $\pi(n)-1$ consecutive multiples of $6$ and so we have that $ G(n) \geq 6(\pi(n)-1)$ (this is a lower bound, which is not a tight one as we will see in the next example).

For $G(17)$ we need $x$ such that $6x+5=0 \mod 5$ and $6(x+1)+5 =0 \mod 7$ and $ 6(x+2)+5 = 0 \mod 11$ and $6(x+3)+5 = 0 \mod 13$ and $ 6(x+4)+5= 0 \mod 17$ and
**we can do it one more time** because $6(x+5)+5 = 0 \mod 5$ and $x=55010$ so as an upper bound we have that $ G(n) \leq 6(\pi(n)-1 +\sum \limits_{i=3}^{\pi(n)} \lfloor \frac{\pi(n)-2}{p_i}\rfloor)$  which is approximately $ \approx 6 \pi(n) (1+ \ln \ln n + M -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}) $ or $ \approx 6 \pi(n ) ( \ln \ln n + 0.428163879514309450422093505275362525718) $ where $M\approx 0.2614972128476427837554268386086958590516$ (Mertens constant)  (This is upper bound because the congruences system might overlap **i don't know**)

But i think the upper bound is tight and furthermore i think it's the correct answer if one could prove that there is a combination of congruences system equations which don't overlap (i might be wrong) but these are the lower and upper bounds.

I really think the upper bound is the actual answer from the tests i ran on java, but NT and numerical evidences are arch nemesis.

Comment: $\pi(n)$ is the prime-counting function approximately $\frac{n}{\ln n}$

Comment: I increment $x$ by $1$ each time to make sure that consecutive multiples of $6$ are sieved out so i was aiming at maximizing the gap

Comment: Oh sorry my previous comment was invalid

Comment: By my understanding $ G(n) \leq 6(\pi(n) - 2)$ is sufficient can you please explain the additional $-1 +\sum \limits_{i=3}^{\pi(n)} \lfloor \frac{\pi(n)-2}{p_i}\rfloor$

Comment: Also I have a question as how can this be yhe upper bound as cycles can collide. Like in G(17), 6(x+5) + 5 may be divided. By 11. Why are the orders of primes maintained along with x, x+1, x+2 etc as numbers get big and cycles get complicated. Am I getting something wrong??

Comment: when cycles can collide (i wrote as overlap) that will make the gap smaller , so i assumed it never do (thus maximizing the gap) and we have we upper bound

Comment: Actually almost from the start we have $G(n)\geq 6(\pi(n)-1)$ , so its never $G(n) \leq 6(\pi(n)-2)$ also the summation  $\sum \limits_{i=3}^{\pi(n)} \lfloor \frac{\pi(n)-2}{p_i}\rfloor$ is taking in account that if for example $ x = 1\mod 5$ then $x+4 =0 \mod 5$ and $ x+9 = 0 \mod 5  , x+14 = 0 \mod 5 , \cdots$ so if i have $\pi(n)$ "big enough" i can use these to extend the gap ( i did an example for $G(17)$)  and so on for $7,11,\cdots$, started from $i=3$ to exclude $2,3$

Comment: when cycles collide it increases the gap. It doesn't decrease it

Comment: your answer has many implicit things which ar not fully explained. Like the synchronicity bw primes and x, x+1 values. The consideration of overlap of cycles which increase the gap. Etc etc. Plz explain them in detail

Comment: I am really bad in explaining, that's Achille's heel in my answers, i did put some examples to explain the formula(I don't know what else to do, may be someone will understand the answer and edit it or give a better answer, you don't have to accept it if you don't fully understand it)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I really appreciate your answer and the work, but I want more easy to understand answer.

Comment: And I personally think the expression for upper bound of gap is not so easy to get as once the prime cycles start colliding the gaps start increasing, that's the main problem I want to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127204/discussion-between-ahmad-and-mr-green-gold).